# Find and replace particular words from a Textbox in Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: .net, string, c++-cli, str-replace

I'm trying to write a program where I can find and replace words written in an old orthography.
For example I have the text "*ads  eajifajefaeof daß*" and want it to change it to "*ads  eajifajefaeof dass*".
So I have 2 textboxes and 1 button and this code:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    String^ content = textBox1->Text;
    IntPtr ptrToNativeString = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(content);
    char* c1 = static_cast<char*>(ptrToNativeString.ToPointer());
    char* pch;
    pch = strstr(c1, "daß");
    strncpy(pch, "dass", 4);
    puts(c1);
    String^ contentnew;
    contentnew = System::Convert::ToString(c1);
    textBox2->Text = contentnew;
}
```

But if I type in some text with the word "*daß*" into textBox1 and click the button textBox2 only shows the word "*true*".
What do I have to change in my code so works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use unmanaged facilities for this: Let the .Net library do it for you.

```
private: void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    String^ content = textBox1->Text;
    String^ contentnew = content->Replace("daß", "dass");
    textBox2->Text = contentnew;
}
```

The reason you're getting "true" is because `Convert::ToString` doesn't know about unmanaged `char*` strings. Overload resolution picked ToString(bool) as the best match, because in C++, all pointers can be converted to bool as a null test. There's a constructor on the String class that would be able to do the conversion, but it's better to just do the work in managed-land.

Comment: It's not `content.Replace` its `content->Replace` but thanks for your help - really helped me out :)

Comment: Quite right, that's what I get for not checking myself with a compiler.